# Opening Access Database with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have this connection string :

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..\Release\DB.accdb"); // Database Connection
```

I want my program to connect to the database without the "..\Release\" in the string.
What I mean is, that i want the program to look for the database in the program's folder, without specifying the folder's name (whatever the folder's name is).
How is that done?

Comment: Have you tried just removing `\Release\` ?

Comment: I tried .. i get this error:'E:\Dangerous\Programming\C# Projects\My Projects\Incompleted Projects\ExaminerApp\ExaminerApp\bin\Debug\...\DB.accdb' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

Comment: well.. thats properly beacuse you dont have a .accdb file in your *Debug* folder.. butting the database in there. The rule of thumb is: in you dont spicify a path, the program will look in the same folder as the `.exe` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add your DB to the project (Add -> Existing Item...) and set `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`:

[image]

After that you can using following connection string:

```
 string cs = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=test.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
```

Following code, will find database file in program folder or sub-folder:

```
string programPath = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).FullName;
var dbPath = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(programPath, "*.accdb", SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault();
string cs = null;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbPath))
{
    cs = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Persist Security Info=False;", dbPath);
}
```

Comment: @John you're welcome. I added code to find db file in sub-folders.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use something like

```
String strAppDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
String strFullPathToMyFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(strAppDir, "DB.accdb");
```

ref:

[How to: Get the Application Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229654%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)